# FFMPEG command is still referring to old build

Tags: linux, compilation, ffmpeg, centos

The version of FFMPEG that came on my server does not have the correct codecs I need for web encoding.

I've followed this guide to completion to recompile FFMPEG on my server https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

Now when I use the FFMPEG, it is still calling the old build as it shows the build date as 2013 and it doesn't have the codecs I chose.

I'm lost as to how I should proceed, I can't find where the new build is located on my server either.

Did I need to uninstall FFMPEG before following the guide? How would I do that?

I'm using CENT OS 6.4

I apologize if this is something obvious, I am new to linux.

Thanks for any help, I'm really stuck on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ffmpeg binary can be found in the `bin` directory under the directory you passed as the `prefix` option to `configure`.

Comment: Note this is generally true for building software with configure/make.

Comment: I was able to figure it out through your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The guide you supplied uses a different installation path which can't be found under default executing environment, you can run the complied ffmpeg with full path which should look like this:$HOME/ffmpeg_build/bin/ffmpeg